# ¿Cómo se forma el plural de números escritos con dígitos?

Tags: plurales, números

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de pluralizar los números escritos con dígitos?

Ejemplo:

> Me pagan los (días) 15 y 30 (de cada mes).

Quisiera saber cómo pluralizar los números, para poder omitir las palabras en paréntesis.

Comment: Chico no he encontrado ninguna fuente de que se pueda poner en plural los números escritos con cifras, Será que cuando  expresas los números  en plural tienes que escribirlos con letras. http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/?key=cardinales&origen=REDPD, por lo otro si tú interlocutor entiende en que contexto estás hablando, este puede entender solo utilizando, `Me pagan/Yo cobro los 15 y los 30`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normalmente no se puede pluralizar un número escrito con dígitos porque, en ese caso, la cifra expresa el número en sí, que es único. El concepto del número 549 es único, no puede tener plural.

Hay casos en que sí podemos usar el nombre de un número en plural; pero en esos casos se debe escribir con letra porque, realmente, es el nombre de algo y, por tanto, una palabra, no un número. Ejemplos:

- Saqué tres dieces en los exámenes finales (*diez* es el nombre de la calificación)
- Necesito dos cuatros para poner el número en la camiseta (*cuatro* es el nombre de una pegatina con forma de número 4)

De todos modos, si encontraras un caso en que fuera correcto usar el plural de una cifra escrita con números, creo que sería de aplicación lo que dice el DPD sobre el [plural de las siglas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=siglas):

> ***Plural***. Aunque en la lengua oral tienden a tomar marca de plural ([oenejés] = ‘organizaciones no gubernamentales’), son invariables en la escritura: las ONG; por ello, cuando se quiere aludir a varios referentes es recomendable introducir la sigla con determinantes que indiquen pluralidad: *Representantes de algunas/varias/numerosas ONG se reunieron en Madrid*. Debe evitarse el uso, copiado del inglés, de realizar el plural de las siglas añadiendo al final una s minúscula, precedida o no de apóstrofo: *CD’s*, *ONGs*.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece mejor:

> Me pagan el 15 y el 30 de cada mes

"Los 15 y 30" suena raro.

A lo mejor, se puede decir:

> Me pagan el 15 y el 30 del mes

No es incorrecto, pero personalmente no me gusta

Answer (score 2):

La Real Academia Española en su `Ortografía de la lengua española (2010)` desaconseja el uso de anadir una s minúscula, precedida o no de un apóstrofe, para indicar la forma plural ([véase](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UuHZoCavNzVmXAFg)).

Desde un punto de vista lógico, la frase `Me pagan los quinces y treintas del mes` es imprecisa porque en un mes solamente hay un día 15 y un día 30.

El visor de n-gramas de Google demuestra que la forma plural es infrecuente ([véase](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=el+quince+de+cada+mes%2C+los+quinces+de+cada+mes%2C+los+quince+de+cada+mes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cel%20quince%20de%20cada%20mes%3B%2Cc0)).

El visor tambien confirma que a la hora de escribir una fecha la forma numérica es mucho mas común que la literal ([véase](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=el+quince+de+cada+mes%2Cel+15+de+cada+mes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cel%20quince%20de%20cada%20mes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cel%2015%20de%20cada%20mes%3B%2Cc0)).

Solamente las fechas que constituyen una nombre propio se escriben con todas sus letras: `el Movimiento Veintiséis de Octubre` ([véase](http://blogs.elpais.com/files/manual-de-estilo-de-el-pa%C3%ADs.pdf) la guía de estilo del Diario El País).

Answer (score 1):

Podrías decir eso sin necesidad de las palabras en los paréntesis y se entendería igual. Los números de por sí ya están pluralizados, el único número singular es el 1.

La palabra "cada" no puede salir de ese contexto, no tendría sentido la construcción:

*Me pagan los 15 y 30 de cada mes.*

**Podrías reemplazarla por otras palabras quizás:**

*Me pagan los 15 y 30 todos los meses.*

Comment: 1) Sí, lo que quiero es omitir dichas palabras. 2) Exacto, lo que no sé es si se puede usar *'s*  ¿Hay algo oficial donde pueda consultarlo?

Comment: Mira mi edición, un texto de referencia no te podría decir, acabo de consultarlo con un lingüista, en cuanto me de una referencia la comento.

Comment: Yo uso las dos últimas opciones, de hecho me pagan en mi trabajo los 15 y 30 de cada mes, este mes cobro un poco antes :)

Answer (score 0):

Usaría

> **Cobro por quincena**

Con esto se sobrentiende que suele ser el 15 y 30 de cada mes.

La RAE define [quincena](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=quincena) como:

> 1. f. Paga que se recibe cada quince días.

Para más información si es febrero o un mes de 31 días véase este articulo  [www.gerencie.com](http://www.gerencie.com/si-el-mes-es-de-31-dias-como-se-paga-la-segunda-quincena.html)

Comment: Gracias, en realidad pude haber pensado en un mejor ejemplo para que no surgiera este malentendido. En realidad no busco una mejor sintaxis (lo cual tu respuesta está dando) sino concretamente el plural de números (en caso de que éste exista).