# ¿Cómo se escribe el plural de las siglas? ¿Es correcto escribir "ONGs"?

Tags: ortografía, plurales, siglas

Con frecuencia en el habla uno oye expresiones del tipo:

> Las [oenegés](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QuqbArn) han estado ayudando a resolver el tema...

Si prescindimos del neologismo *oenegé* y usamos sus siglas originales, entra la duda: ¿cómo marcamos su plural?

> Las **ONG** han estado ayudando...

o

> Las **ONGs** han estado ayudando...

Comment: Esta información tambien estaba en la [respuesta de Gorpik](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/5094/1674) a la pregunta _¿Cómo se forma el plural de números escritos con dígitos?_. Al ser cosas diferentes, añado pregunta ad hoc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lo correcto es decir ***las ONG*** y no ⓧ *ONGs*.

Del artículo [*sigla*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=nNmc4LzNaD6zHPhgWc) del Diccionario panhispánico de dudas:

> 3. Plural. Aunque en la lengua oral tienden a tomar marca de plural ([oenejés] = ‘organizaciones no gubernamentales’), son invariables en la escritura: *las ONG*; por ello, **cuando se quiere aludir a varios referentes es recomendable introducir la sigla con determinantes que indiquen pluralidad**: *Representantes de algunas/varias/numerosas ONG se reunieron en Madrid*. **Debe evitarse el uso, copiado del inglés, de realizar el plural de las siglas añadiendo al final una s minúscula, precedida o no de apóstrofo**: ⓧ CD’s, ⓧ ONGs.

Comentario personal: se parece al caso del francés con los plurales, que se escriben distinto pero se pronuncian igual y es el determinante el que indica el número.

Comment: Yo uso estas mismas reglas con las etiquetas de HTML, digo los `div`, los `span`, etc. Pero no sabría como buscar eso para ver si es así realmente ¿que tipo de palabras son esos términos?

Comment: @blonfu lo ignoro y daría para una pregunta interesante. Me da que aplicaría la regla de los anglicismos, que [básicamente](http://www.amigospais-guaracabuya.org/oagbv003.php) se traduce en que cada caso es un mundo.

Comment: Sí, creo que formularé una pregunta, a ver como la planteo.

Comment: @blonfu - piensa en un grupo indígena -- por ejemplo *los maya*.

Comment: Se dice *los mayas*

Comment: @blonfu exacto, ya lo hablamos en los comentarios a la pregunta [Validez del plural “los mapuche” sin -s final, al tratarse de una etnia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21055/1674), con referencia al artículo del DPD [_plurales_](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i).

Comment: @fedorqui no sabía que había discusión en ese tema, para mi era lo lógico, todas las tribus, etnias o pueblos que conozco tienen plural y así lo he oído siempre: los mayas, los apaches, los pigmeos, los vascos... Solo se me ocurre *los sioux* sin plural pero acaba en *x* y supongo que eso lo hace especial

Answer (score 1):

Siempre había pensado que para el caso de siglas en plural se duplicaban las letras iniciales.

Es el caso de BBDD (Bases de Datos) y RRHH (Recursos Humanos), por ejemplo.

Lo que nunca he visto es que se dupliquen con tres letras o más (ONG)

Comment: Es diferente. Como [explica Fundéu](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/rr-hh-733/): _Se trata de la regla para formar las abreviaturas de los nombres formados por dos palabras en plural: se duplican las letras iniciales, se escriben en mayúscula y van seguidas por el punto abreviativo y un espacio tipográfico: RR. HH._ En este caso no se trata de palabras plurales (el "no" se mantiene invariable) y, además, son tres palabras y no dos.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, 'fedorqui'. Pensaba que eran siglas y no abreviaturas...

Comment: Darkov: tu respuesta me ha despertado una duda, así que la he planteado en [¿Cuándo se duplican las letras iniciales en las abreviaturas? ¿Cómo se deben escribir?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21910/1674). Aprovecha para darle a [edit] y añadir referencias a tu respuesta, así será más útil. Lee [answer] y pásate por el [tour] si te apetece conocer más sobre el sitio :)