# ¿Qué tipo de palabras son las etiquetas HTML?

Tags: gramática, solicitud-de-término, plurales

En la pregunta [¿Cómo se escribe el plural de las siglas?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21885/c%C3%B3mo-se-escribe-el-plural-de-las-siglas-es-correcto-escribir-ongs/21886#21886) -donde quedó claro que no se les pone una *s* al final sino que se mantienen tal cual- comenté que yo seguía ese criterio con las etiquetas HTML y digo *«tres `div`»*, *«los `ul` y sus `li`»*; no los pluralizo y además siempre los pongo en masculino.

En realidad, no sé que reglas aplicarían en este caso y no sabría cómo buscar ya que no sé qué tipo de palabras son, si es que son palabras (supongo que sí). ¿Tienen un nombre o están dentro de alguna categoría que yo no adivino?

Muchas de estas etiquetas se pueden traducir al elemento que representan, `ul` sería *lista desordenada* o `a` *enlace* pero otras como `div` o `span` no es tan claro. Tambien puedo decir *«las etiquetas `div`»* o *«los elementos `span`»* por ejemplo y me evito problemas pero aún así me gustaría saber qué son estos términos y qué reglas gramaticales podrían aplicarse a ellos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En este caso yo diría que se están usando como sustantivos, pero solamente porque el elemento al que representan es a su vez un sustantivo:

- `div` equivale a *división* (de la página).
- `li` equivale a *elemento* (de la lista).
- `hr` equivale a *línea* (horizontal).

(Hay que tener claro que una cosa es el elemento representado —el elemento estructural de una página HTML— y otra el texto "<div>" o "div" usado en la oración.)

Todos los elementos representados (división, elemento, línea) corresponden con sustantivos, y por tanto al usar sus nombres de etiquetas ("div", "li", "hr") en el lenguaje se usan también como sustantivos. Si se usa como *el div* o *los div*, es cierto que estás sustantivizando los nombres de las etiquetas. Si dices *los elementos div*, es un apócope de "los elementos titulados 'div'", y entonces 'div' actuaría como un título de etiqueta, igual que si dijeras "los libros titulados 'El señor de los anillos'".

Nótese que esta sustantivización se realiza únicamente porque las etiquetas representan sustantivos. ¿Qué pasaría si las etiquetas representaran cualquier otra cosa? En XML se pueden crear etiquetas representando cualquier cosa. ¿Y si la etiqueta fuese `<azul>` o `<rojo>`? ¿Diríamos *los azul* o *los rojo*? ¿Y si fuese `<ElementosClasificadosPorColor>` o `<ElementosFacturadosPendientes>`? Entonces hablaríamos simplemente de "los elementos clasificados por color" o simplemente de "la etiqueta 'ElementosFacturadosPendientes'". Y entonces actuaría nuevamente como un título.

Aclarar que los títulos de obras [se suelen asemejar en las oraciones a los nombres propios](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QudQkJJbrEqSOFWE) (*Nueva gramática*, párrafo 12.8p), por tanto equivaldrían a un sustantivo compuesto por un grupo nominal. Así que al final sí, en cualquier caso estaríamos hablando de sustantivos.

En cuanto a si decir "los div" o "los divs", mi opinión es que es irrelevante. Por un lado, se podría suponer que "div" es un sustantivo invariable en plural (como es el caso de "análisis"). Por otro lado, se podrían aplicar las reglas básicas de pluralización de los sustantivos (sería "divs"). O se podría pensar que "los div" es una contracción de "los elementos div" (siguiendo las mismas reglas que en "[los países miembro](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17474/12637)"). La palabra a fin de cuentas es un neologismo, y por tanto las reglas te las puedes inventar tú. Y lo mismo con el resto de palabras ("li"/"lis", "hr"/"hrs", etc.).

Answer (score 7):

Pues tal y como los estás usando, son sustantivos. De hecho puedes decir "los *div*". Si dices "la etiqueta *div*· estaría funcionando como aposición.

Desde luego, son palabras de otro idioma, así que deben tratarse como tales: con cursiva o comillas.

Comment: Me recuerdan de los colores: tienen las cualidades (por ejemplo el genero) de un substantivo que no está visible (color: el [color] rojo), no son físicas y describen altun tipo de nombre o calificador único.

Comment: Entonces sería  "los divs", según el DPD: *Sustantivos y adjetivos terminados en consonantes distintas de -l, -r, -n, -d, -z, -j, -s, -x, -ch. Se trate de onomatopeyas o de voces procedentes de otras lenguas, hacen el plural en -s*

Comment: @blonfu - Creo que hubo una pregunta sobre eso hace un par de meses.  Si mal no recuerdo, la respuesta aceptada apoyó esta manera de hacer el plural: "los *div*".

Comment: @aparente001 no veo nada parecido, si encuentras la pregunta pon el enlace por aquí.

Comment: @aparente001 los moderadores no tenemos más información al respecto de la que puedas buscar tú :) Buscando [`plural created:3m is:a`](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=plural+created%3A3m+is%3Aa) se observan cosas, pero no sé qué tienes exactamente en mente.

Comment: @fedorqui - No tengo buena memoria y esta semana tengo algo que entregar en un par de días, perdón.  Tengo la impresión de que la tertulia está más activa ahora.  Quizás si preguntaras ahí....